# What's the best way to reset a timer signal?

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa, nstimeinterval, racsignal

I need to fetch data from server every 5 minutes. If I do pull down refresh, also need to fetch data from server, and **reset the timer**.

Below code is the solution now, looks works fine. Just wonder how to simplify the code? Probable there's better way in `ReactiveCocoa`?

```
    RACSignal* refreshSignal = [self.refreshControl rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    self.timerSignal = [[RACSignal interval:300 onScheduler:[RACScheduler scheduler] withLeeway:2] takeUntil:refreshSignal];
    [self.timerSignal subscribeNext:^(id x) {
        NSLog(@"==========================");
        NSLog(@"[Timer1]");
        [self.viewModel performFetch];
    }];

    [refreshSignal subscribeNext:^(id x) {
        NSLog(@"==========================");
        NSLog(@"[Refresh]");
        [self.viewModel performFetch];
        self.timerSignal = [[RACSignal interval:300 onScheduler:[RACScheduler scheduler] withLeeway:2] takeUntil:refreshSignal];
        [self.timerSignal subscribeNext:^(id x) {
            NSLog(@"==========================");
            NSLog(@"[Timer2]");
            [self.viewModel performFetch];
        }];
    }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest way that I can think of would be using a `RACReplaySubject`, sending `interval` signals of 300 and then switching to the latest signal sent every time the block is fired.

```
self.timerSubject = [RACReplaySubject replaySubjectWithCapacity:1];
RACSignal * refreshSignal = [self.refreshControl rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
RACSignal * timeSignal = [RACSignal interval:300 onScheduler:[RACScheduler scheduler] withLeeway:2];
[self.timerSubject sendNext:timeSignal];

@weakify(self)
[[self.timerSubject.switchToLatest merge:refreshSignal] subscribeNext:^(id _) {
    @strongify(self)
    [self.viewModel performFetch];
}];

[refreshSignal subscribeNext:^(id _) {
    @strongify(self)
    [self.timerSubject sendNext:timeSignal];
}];
```

Comment: Yes, your code is much cleaner then mine. Just not familiar with RACReplaySubject.

Comment: `RACReplaySubject` is a sort-of "manual" signal. It's like the mutable variable equivalent of the functional reactive world. You manually tell it when to send `next`, `error` and `completed`. Since it has a capacity of `1`, it stores the last sent `next` and forwards it to any new subscriptions.

Comment: I have tested your code, just one small problem(or may be it's feature): the delay may delay 300 or 301 seconds, and it don't like timer with withLeeway to make the interval offset back; What timer give is if it's 301 seconds, next time it can set back to 209 seconds to make it sable.

Comment: But your code is good suggestion for me. I just think that 300 on average would be better. Just because the accumulative effect of offset would become huge.

Comment: Edited to use a timer.

Comment: I have edit to include a start signal. sendNext:[RACSignal return:nil]

Comment: And I was never think about sendNext: with a signal before, your answer broaden my horizons.

Comment: Glad to help, I hope it's good enough to be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would map the refreshSignal to a timer signal. Every time the refreshSignal sends a value it is mapped to a signal sending a value every five minutes.

As a side note I think this logic belongs in the view model. There the resulting signal could be mapped to a network request with `flatMap:`. Then an ongoing network request would be cancelled if the user refreshes again quickly.

```
[[[[refreshSignal startWith:nil]
map:^id(id value) {
    return [[RACSignal interval:5 * 60 onScheduler:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]] startWith:nil];
}]
switchToLatest]
subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    @strongify(self)
    [self.viewModel performFetch];
}];
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay, I will test yours later.